# BootstrapVue in VueJS 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to use bootstrap-vue on my Vue-JS 3 project, but i got an error

Using npm run serve

[image: 1]

And in my browser I got

Error on the browser

[image: 2]

i used this command in my terminal

```
npm install vue bootstrap bootstrap-vue
```

and here is my main.js code

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'

// Import Bootstrap and BootstrapVue CSS files (order is important)
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

createApp(App).use(BootstrapVue).use(IconsPlugin).mount('#app')
```

Anyone knows how to fix it? I saw is because something had changed from Vue 2 to 3, but i saw a project in Vue JS 3 already running with bootstrap so i guess this bug have fixed

Comment: From the BootstrapVue website: "Vue.js v2.6 is required, v2.6.12 is recommended." It doesn't support Vue 3.

Comment: Oh, okay man, thanks, i'll try to use VueJS 2 so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem: Bootstrap-Vue is not yet compatible with Vue.js 3.

Answer (score 0):

https://cdmoro.github.io/bootstrap-vue-3/

Use this its not fully released but works well, I'm using it in a several projects

cheers